# Preparing "Extrude & Bevel" effects for export as SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

I used Illustrator's effect  "Extrude & Bevel ..." on some svg-icons. Before exporting, I use "Object - Expand..." which results in many shapes on top of each other.

Usually you have to subtract the surfaces from each other, but I do not know why.

Is it really necessary to strip all surfaces from each other? If so, why? Or should I not use "Object - Expand..."?

Comment: It doesn't matter if objects overlap in an SVG, there's nothing in the format that says they can't.

Comment: ok, thx! And how do you know that? why do people usually subtract the surfaces from each other?

Comment: I've added my comments as an answer now.

Comment: @Martina i do not think they usually do that.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if objects overlap in an SVG. There is nothing in the format that says objects can't overlap. There is no need to subtract objects from each other for display in a web browser, unless you need it for some other reason you didn't mention.

Try it yourself and you will see. Create an SVG, then open it with your browser. Here's [an example SVG](http://svgshare.com/s/5oK) made in Illustrator, from a Bevel and Extrude object, expanded appearance, and overlaid with multiple objects.

Expanding the appearance of a "Bevel and Extrude" effect is the only way to get it to work in an SVG. SVGs don't support Illustrator's native effects, only SVG effects.

Comment: ok great thx. I have already tried it. I know it works in the browser, but I do not know why some people want or do that.

Comment: @Martina I have no idea, you should ask them. Perhaps they need the SVGs for something else, like vinyl cutting, or perhaps they have OCD.

Comment: yes. thx Billy Kerr